# Flow<T>.distinctUntilChanged() is not working

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm **trying to** have a coroutine run while a SharedFlow is active (`subscriptionCount` is greater than zero) and be cancelled when the count drops. But somehow even something as simple as `distinctUntilChanged()` is not working as it should and I'm baffled.

For this I'm making a "onActive" extension like this:

```
fun <T : Any> MutableSharedFlow<T>.onActive(
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit
): Flow<T> {

    val original = this

    val isActiveFlow: Flow<Boolean> = subscriptionCount
        .map {
            println("Class: Count is $it")
            it > 0
        }
        .distinctUntilChanged()

    return isActiveFlow.flatMapLatest { isActive ->
        println("Class: isActive is $isActive")
        // here would be the code that calls `block`
        // but just this exactly as is, already triggers the error

        original // still emits the original flow, 
                 // that is needed or else subscriptionCount never changes
    }
}
```

This initially this seems to work, but running a test on it that adds several subscribers, will print "isActive is true" several times in a row. Why is `distinctUntilChanged()` not working? This repeated call messes-up with the rest of the logic in the redacted area.

The test is like this:

```
    @Test
    fun `onActive is called only once with multiple subscribers`() = runBlocking {

        val flow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>(
            replay = 2,
            onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST
        ).apply {
            repeat(5) { tryEmit(it) }
        }.onActive {

        }

        val jobs = mutableListOf<Job>()
        repeat(3) { count ->
            jobs.add(flow.onEach {
                println("Test:  Listener $count received $it")
            }.launchIn(this))
        }
        delay(100)
        jobs.forEach { it.cancel() }
        jobs.forEach { it.join() }
    }
```

running this the output is:

```
Class: Count is 0
Class: isActive is false
Class: Count is 1
Class: Count is 1
Class: isActive is true
Class: Count is 2
Class: Count is 2
Class: isActive is true
Class: Count is 3
Test:  Listener 0 received 3
Test:  Listener 0 received 4
Test:  Listener 1 received 3
Test:  Listener 1 received 4
Test:  Listener 2 received 3
Test:  Listener 2 received 4
Class: Count is 2
Class: isActive is true
Class: Count is 3
Class: Count is 3
Class: Count is 3
Test:  Listener 0 received 3
Test:  Listener 0 received 4
```

So the question, why is `distinctUntilChanged()` not working and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't see any `distinctUntilChanged` or `foobar` call in the test, is this expected?

EDIT: ok you named it `foobar` in the declaration, but the actual method name is `onActive`

Comment: It would actually be nice to share the redacted part, because this might affect how it works

Comment: Have you looked into `SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed` by the way? It looks what you want could be more easily written by just using a regular flow, and then sharing it with `shareIn(started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed)`

Comment: @Joffrey hi. Thanks for checking my issue. Yeah, I had several versions of the method and at some point was just foobar. I edited the post to be all properly called `onActive`.  Call to `distinctUntilChanged()` is in the method I'm trying to write, not in the test. I imagine the redacted part can change things, BUT, I actually removed from this version of the method to isolate the problem. Currently the `flatMapLatest` is just println and returns the original flow.

Comment: hi @Joffrey, from what I see `SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed` is used when calling `shareIn`, but what I need is a `block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit` to be executed when isActive is true and have that CoroutineScope cancelled when isActive is false. I don't see how I could link that with `SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed`

Comment: Is that coroutine supposed to emit elements to the shared flow? Or is it really just a "side thing" you want to happen? I'm asking because it feels strange to register it in the middle of the flow definition if it's "just on the side" - it makes you do things like this `flatMapLatest` returning the original flow

Comment: @Joffrey it is just on the side, but I was "trying to" make it happen without the need of injecting an external/parent CoroutineScope. Meaning, it would use as parent the CoroutineScope of whoever is collecting the returned Flow. (I agree it's kind of weird)

Comment: The `shareIn` approach is only meaningful if the launched coroutine produces elements in the flow. Otherwise I would go for an external coroutine that's launched independently (in its own scope) to collect `subscriptionCount` and control the "sidecar" coroutine. *it would use as parent the CoroutineScope of whoever is collecting the returned Flow* - but there are multiple subscribers, which one then? Cancelling the wrong subscriber would cancel the coroutine, which could end badly. It seems the coroutine is conceptually independent, so it feels natural to provide a separate scope for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the behaviour you're seeing is actually correct as far as `distinctUntilChanged` is concerned:

- the first registered subscriber collects the original 2 replayed elements with the starting `isActive=false` value
- then `isActive` becomes true because of that first susbcription, so that first subscriber recollects the original flow due to `flatMapLatest`, and thus gets again the replayed elements
- the other 2 subscribers arrive when the `subscriptionCount` is already non-0 so `isActive` stays true for them until they are cancelled

If the coroutine you launch "while there are subscribers" is meant to produce elements in the `SharedFlow`, I would rather define the flow like a `channelFlow`/`callbackFlow` initially, and then use [shareIn](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/share-in.html) with `SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed` to have this "run when there are susbcribers" behaviour.

If it's "just on the side", you probably want an external scope and just launch a coroutine separately to listen to `sharedFlow.subscribersCount` and start/stop the "sidecar" coroutine.

Comment: From your explanation, the `map/distinctUntilChanged/flatMapLatest` is happening. for each subscription and not just once when the `onActive` method is invoke. I'm sure there's a good explanation for that, but certainly a somewhat surprising behavior.

Comment: Just for FYI, the final final goal here was to have a `while(true) { emit(refresh()); delay(duration) }` to keep refreshing the value while there's a subscriber.  The path I tried (and fail here) was to have a isActiveFlow, to call the block() with a new CoroutineScope that I could cancel when `isActive==false`. Probably could do something using the standard Flow factory `flow { ` if there was a way to check `hasSubscribers` in the while loop. I'll go back to drawing board. Thanks.

Comment: @Budius regarding your first comment, this is indeed how `Flow` works in general. The only "shared" part is the `SharedFlow` itself (or everything up to a `shareIn` operator when you create the `SharedFlow` that way). Otherwise, all operators are applied independently for all collectors.

Comment: @Budius if by "refreshing the value" you're referring to a value in the shared flow, then why not build it as a `channelFlow` or `callbackFlow` with this built-in refresh loop and then use `shareIn`? I thought that side coroutine was not about sending values to the flow

Comment: *Probably could do something using the standard Flow factory flow {  if there was a way to check hasSubscribers in the while loop* - that's exactly what `shareIn(started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed)` would do. You don't worry about checking `hasSubscribers` manually, but the initial `flow { }` content is cancelled and restarted when it drops to 0

Comment: @Budius something like this: https://pl.kotl.in/cECza6x_I

Comment: Hey, that theoretically should work. The most complex there for me (around the whole huge project) is to find the right `sharedFlowScope` to do the cancellation when the user logs out. That's the main bit that I was trying to avoid. But yeah I'll give a try. Thanks again!